# Sourcetree 1.5.2 update for Windows not tracking local changes

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

After updating to SourceTree version 1.5.2 (windows 8) my local working copy changes are not being tracked by the SourceTree application. I can open up git terminal, do a git status and see the changes, but those changes are no longer reflected by Sourcetree's Working copy changes. The only way I've been able to see the changes has been closing and re-opening the application.

Tools -> options -> Refresh automatically is checked.

Comment: Have you considered reporting the issue to Atlassian? Maybe it's a bug? I wouldn't be able to help you reproduce the issue, I don't have Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone runs into this in the future, I solved this by removing and re-adding my repository to source tree. This is definitely something I should have tried before posting...